# python no aparece en el Vscode

Tags: python, vscode

Hola instale python correctamente, modifique lo de las variables de entorno pero cuando quiero abrir un archivo .py no se abre con el interprete en python ni tampoco aparece python en el selector de interprete del vscode
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Se que voy a hacer una pregunta tonta por la imagen. Pero todo aporta. Instalaste la extensión de Python de vscode? Sin eso vscode no sabe ni que es Python.

Comment: lo mismo pense pero desintalo e instalo la extension y sigue sin resolverse

Answer (score 0):

soy nuevo en la programación y tu problema me paso a mi hace 3 meses cuando empecé con  python.. yo desinstale la extensión e ingrese en https://www.python.org/ descargue la versión recomendada y luego instale la extencion en vscode

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).